# Send Ctrl-C to process open by Java

Tags: java, windows

Under Windows OS.

I start a sub-process via a Runtime.getRuntime().exec();
I want to send a "ctrl-c" to the process to stop it.

I did a small example, with Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping google.com -n 100000");
The code can be found there : http://pastebin.com/f6315063f

So far, I tried to send the char '3' (ctrl-C character) via Process outputStream.

Here is a bit of code:

```
 cmd = re.exec("ping google.com -n 10000"); 
 out = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(cmd.getOutputStream()));
 input =  new BufferedReader (new  InputStreamReader(cmd.getInputStream()));


 char ctrlBreak = (char)3;
 //Different testing way to send the ctrlBreak;
 out.write(ctrlBreak);
 out.flush();
 out.write(ctrlBreak+"\n");
 out.flush();
```

I don't want to kill the process, I just want to send a Ctrl-C signal.
How can I do that?

Comment: Ultimately, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do a wrapper around a old  DOS/windows3.1/win95 application

Comment: it should work but you should send break only once, doing it twice would obviously kill the main process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe Ctrl-C is caught by the shell and translated into a signal ([SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29)) which is sent to the underlying process (in this case your spawned process).

So I think you'll need to get the process id and then send the appropriate signal to that process. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912889/how-to-send-interrupt-key-sequence-to-a-java-process) appears to be very similar and points to various resources of use.

Comment: I saw that question but SendSignal send only a ctrl-break signal.

Comment: So I think then you need to find the process id and send the SIGINT via (perhaps) a POSIX function or similar.

Answer (score 3):

After lots and lots of trials, I found a solution that I like now.
Basically, it works like this:
1. Get the Process ID of the process that you started
2. Pass this PID to a slightly modified version of SendSignal.exe, which sends Ctrl-C instead of Ctrl-Break

Both steps are not completely straight forward, but nearly.
For 1. you need to get the PID. Java does not provide any native way to get it.
There are a number of threads discussing about how to do that best.
I decided for one where you need to now the name (see getProcessIDs() in the code below).

For 2. you need to have a tool that sends CTRL-C to a given PID. Again, Java does not do this.
There are different ways to do it (e.g. using a wrapper in python or so), but all of them are somewhat complicated. I found the easiest one is to use a .exe-File to do the job. For this, I modified SendSingal.exe. You can get the sourcecode here: 1. Then, simply replace all occurences of "BREAK" (also in lowercase letters) by "C" and recompile.

Rename the exe to SendSignalC.exe and put it in a subfolder ext\ of where you start Java. Then run the code below and happily call e.g. SendCTRLC.sendCtrlC("howeveryourprogramiscall.exe").

```
/** 
 * Sends CTRL-C to running processes from Java (in Windows)
 * and ca get ProcessID(s) for a given process name.
 * IMPORTANT!
 * This function NEEDS SendSignalC.exe in the ext\ subdirectory.
 * @author Kai Goergen
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SendCTRLC() {


    /**
     * Get all PIDs for a given name and send CTRL-C to all
     * @param processName
     * @return
     */
    public static List<String> sendCTRLC(String processName) {
        // get all ProcessIDs for the processName
        List<String> processIDs = getProcessIDs(processName);
        System.out.println("" + processIDs.size() + " PIDs found for " + processName + ": " + processIDs.toString());
        for (String pid : processIDs) {
            // close it
            sendCTRLC(Integer.parseInt(pid));
        }
        return processIDs;
    }

    /**
     * Send CTRL-C to the process using a given PID
     * @param processID
     */
    public static void sendCTRLC(int processID) {
        System.out.println(" Sending CTRL+C to PID " + processID);
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ext\\SendSignalC.exe " + processID);
            StreamGobbler.StreamGobblerLOGProcess(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get List of PIDs for a given process name
     * @param processName
     * @return
     */
    public static List<String> getProcessIDs(String processName) {
        List<String> processIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            String line;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist /v /fo csv");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
                    // Pid is after the 1st ", thus it's argument 3 after splitting
                    String currentProcessName = line.split("\"")[1];
                    // Pid is after the 3rd ", thus it's argument 3 after splitting
                    String currentPID = line.split("\"")[3];
                    if (currentProcessName.equalsIgnoreCase(processName)) {
                        processIDs.add(currentPID);
                    }
                }
            }
            input.close();
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        return processIDs;

    }
}
```

PS: I would love to attach SendSignalC.exe here, but I don't think that I'm allowed to. Anyhow, the changes are simple and straight-forward if you have a running cpp-compiler...

Comment: @soulseekah - StreamGobbler.StreamGobblerLOGProcess(p); package not found. I want to quit an service which is running over cmd, so never quit need to  press cntrol + c or any other machnism, please share if you know anything about it

Answer (score 2):

Switch to Java 9 and save your time, `Process` has `pid` property now, check the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#pid--) for details. You can easily kill another process like this:

```
long pid = process.pid();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill " + pid);
```

Comment: He does not want to kill the process, only send a Ctrl-C signal.

Comment: If that processing does not respond to kill signal you can use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 " + pid)

Answer (score 0):

To terminate you can `taskkill` `java` with this code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im java.exe");
```

Hope this help!