# How to interrupt/ stop a java ping command in Windows?

Tags: java, runtime, interrupt

I got a sample ping program with a little modification...

```
    String ip = "192.168.1.1 -t";
    String pingResult = "";      
    String pingCmd = "ping " + ip;

    try{

        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("time=(\\d+)ms");
        Matcher m = null;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            m = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(1));
            }
        }
        in.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

I going to implement a GUI which include a start and exit button, the start button works but the exit buttons won't. When I click the exit button, the program do not show the rtt time output. But the program do not actually exit-ed/ stopped. How am I totally to shut it down, am I going to add something like`Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook`.

Need some hints and guidelines, thanks in advanced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ping's `-n` parameter and start after n pings again or stop if user required to halt.

`Process` has also an OutputStream. You may try to send a Ctrl-C when you want to stop ping.

Comment: thanks, for certainty. Am I going to pass something like 

char ctrlBreak = (char)3;

into the Process p OutputStream?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835885/send-ctrl-c-to-process-open-by-java

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isStoped=false;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null && (!isStoped)) {
            m = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(1));
            }
        }
```

make `isStoped=true` and call `p.destroy()` when you click the exit button. Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks a lot, but the p.destroy() only can stop the print line but not the ping program which run on the background of the Threads... Thanks for the idea...