# Send ctrl+d to kill a process Java

Tags: java

I am starting a server using Java:

```
private void startServerButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                               
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "activator run"};
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ProcessBuilder processbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
                    processbuilder.directory(new File("D:\\temp"));
                    Process process = processbuilder.start();

                    IOThreadHandler thread = new IOThreadHandler(process.getInputStream());
                    thread.start();
                    // TODO : Server name as key
                    serverProcessMap.put("service", process);

                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DevUtilsUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DevUtilsUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Now I am trying to kill the same process by passing Ctrl+d. Ctrl+d equivalent is number 4. But it is not working. Why it is not working? I am pasting the Java code for stopping the process:

```
 OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(4);
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
```

I referenced this from the following link: [Send Ctrl-C to process open by Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835885/send-ctrl-c-to-process-open-by-java)

Comment: Why don't you try with just `os.close()`. After all, CTRL+D signals than STDIN is closed (which is what happens when you close `os`). Also note that a process does not need to die just because stdin is closed; any process that does not use stdin will probably just ignore that... and your process is "CMD", not "activator"

Comment: Then how can i kill the process mate?