# Kill process which was started from Java from a batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, process

I have a third party .bat file (wso2server.bat) which start a server.

I'm starting it by

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd /C start cmd /C  C:\wso\wso2esb-4.9.0\bin\wso2server.bat);
```

I tried to stop this

```
process.destroy();  
and
process.destroyForcibly();
```

The process.isAlive() returns "false" after destroy. But the server still running!

I also tried to run with

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(params);
process = pb.start();
```

and stop it, but it doesn't matter, how I start it, the java.exe - and the server - still running and I can not stop it. 
I think this is because .bat starts another process...

So, how can I stop this java.exe?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\wso\wso2esb-4.9.0\bin\wso2server.bat");`? or possibly even `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\wso\wso2esb-4.9.0\bin\wso2server.bat");`?

Comment: cmd /c start : the server starts, but can not stop it (the same as above)

But with  cmd /c  :  the server doesn't start. The java.exe appears in Task Manager, but the Http Site unavailable.

Comment: start in this case is not an instruction to the server, it is an instruction to the batch file, I do not understand why `cmd /c file.bat` wouldn't start the server. What is the content of your bat file?

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/product-ss/blob/master/modules/distribution/src/main/bin/wso2server.bat

Comment: It is my understanding that in Windows you would start the server using `C:\wso\wso2esb-4.9.0\bin\wso2server.bat --run` and are required to excecute `Ctrl-C` in that cmd.exe window to stop that server.

Comment: Yes, but how can I send a Ctrl-c to that cmd.exe? I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835885/send-ctrl-c-to-process-open-by-java  but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start` command does not wait for process completion, so you can not control the server process if the batch command just runs the server and exits.

Use `start /wait ...` command to run the batch file. `start /wait` will wait for process completion, so you will have a process tree like

```
cmd "start"
    cmd "batch"
        server
```

To kill the process tree use `taskkill /pid N /t /f` command.

To get the PID of the root `cmd` process

- setup `cmd` title to `root_cmd`
- get a process list
- find the process with the window title `root_cmd`
- extract the PID and save it to the `%TEMP%/pid.txt`

  ```
  title root_cmd
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %A in ('tasklist /v /fo csv ^| findstr root_cmd') do echo %~A>"%TEMP%/pid.txt"
  ```

Combine all together

- run the server `cmd /c "title root_cmd & (for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %A in ('tasklist /v /fo csv ^| findstr root_cmd') do echo %~A>"%TEMP%/pid.txt") & start /wait "" cmd /c wso2server.bat"`
- kill the server `set /p PID=<"%TEMP%/pid.txt" & call taskkill /pid %PID% /t /f`

**Update.**

For Java:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Runtime;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        try {
            if (args.length < 1) {
                System.out.println("Start server");
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "cmd", "/c", "start /wait \"launcher_cmd\" s.bat"});
            } else {
                System.out.println("Stop server");
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "cmd", "/c", "taskkill /fi \"WINDOWTITLE eq launcher_cmd*\" /t /f"});
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason `for ...`, `echo ...>filename` commands run by `exec` are not working as expected. So I have modified the method:

- `start /wait "title" command` will setup cmd's title and run the batch file
- `taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq launcher_cmd*" /t /f` will kill the `cmd "title"` process and its descendants
- since we use `cmd /c` everywhere the root process will also exit after children will be killed

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried this command:    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"title root_cmd & (for /f \"tokens=2 delims=,\" %A in ('tasklist /v /fo csv ^| findstr root_cmd') do echo %~A>\"%TEMP%/pid.txt\") & start /wait \"\" cmd /c C:\\wso\\wso2esb-4.9.0\\bin\\wso2server.bat");
            Unfortunately, it starts 2 cmd window, but does not start the server. Print screen: https://ibb.co/mX9HWF

Comment: Added Java example.